# Fixing AWS Application Load Balancer connection timeouts under small loads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, connection-timeout

I'm currently using an application load balancer to split traffic between 3 instance.

Testing the individual instance (connection via IP), they are able to handle about ~200req/second without any connection timeout (timeout being set a 5 seconds).

As such, I'd assume that load balancing over all 3 of them would scale this up to ~600req/second (there's no bottleneck further down the pipe to stop this).

However, when sending the exact same type of test requests to an application load balancer, the connections start to time out before I even hit 100req/second.

I already eliminated the possibly of a low down due to HTTPS (by just sending the requests over HTTP), the instance themselves are healthy and not under heavy use an the load balancer reports no "errors".

I've also configured IP stickiness for ~20 minutes to try and improve the situation but it hasn't helped one bit.

What could be the cause of this problem ? I found no information about increasing the network capacity of LB on aws and no similar questions, so I'm bound to be doing something wrong, but I'm quite unsure what that something is.

Comment: What's timing out? Your connection to the balancer?  Are you monitoring and using all the IP addresses in the DNS answers for the balancer?

Comment: ' Are you monitoring and using all the IP addresses in the DNS answers for the balancer?' I'm not sure what you mean by this to be honest. Were those supposed to be two questions. The timeout I have set on the testing end is 5 seconds (the LB timeout if 60).  "Your connection to the balancer?" Again, not sure what you mean by this, what is my avg ping time to the LB ? Do I have an unintrerupted connection to the LB ? How am I connecting to it ?

Comment: The DNS query to the balancer returns multiple IP addresses.  Are you using all of them, or just one?  And, are you observing whether they change while you are testing?

Comment: Ah, fair enough, that may be the issue. I have no idea if the test is using one or multiple addresses, as I use the aws provided domain name. I wasn't aware the load balancer work by redirecting queries to multiple machine. I'

Comment: I'll try forcing DNS resolval every x request and see if that changes things by balancing the requests among multiple IPs.

Comment: This looks to be an interesting issue. Any update on this George?